# How can I use html content in meta data of the head in nuxt

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have an endpoint coming from the backend containing HTML content. I want to use the endpoint in the meta tag of the HTML head using nuxt. I have this error on the console when I try to output what I have [Error from output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVNZM.png)

Below is my code:
[Code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILV8M.png)
and this is coming from the backend
[Data from endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPPIM.png)

Comment: I'm not sure what the `metadata` computed property returns, but Nuxt expects `meta` to be an array and array has a function `filter` so maybe Nuxt is calling that function but `meta` is not an array.

Answer (score 0):

[Nuxt head (meta)](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/meta-tags-seo/) looks like this:

[image]

You are trying to use a string of concatenated meta tags from your backend which will not work. You'll have to convert the string into an array of objects and use it as per the image above.

When the page is rendered in the browser, the meta tags will be formatted properly (as regular HTML meta tags).